# How to extract folder name from Path

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
from pathlib import Path
Path("/shared/code-folder").resolve()
```

It gives:

```
PosixPath('/shared/rev-383837338838373')
```

I want to extract the sub folder `rev-383837338838373` as string.
How can I extract it from the `PosixPath` object?

Edit:
i can't do:
PosixPath('/shared/rev-383837338838373').stem

As you see in my input code I don't know that code-folder is linked to rev-383837338838373. The rev-383837338838373 is changed every few min. It's a dynamic sys link.  My goal here is to find the name of `rev-383837338838373` every time I run the code.
When I run

```
Path("/shared/code-folder").resolve()
```

I can give:

```
PosixPath('/shared/rev-383837338838373')
```

or

```
   PosixPath('/shared/rev-141341341431')
```

or any other folder path I don't know what it will be.

Comment: I can't do that because I don't know rev-383837338838373 it's a dynamic value as shown by the resolve.

Comment: `Path("/shared/code-folder").resolve().stem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stem` attribute of `PosixPath` to get what you what.

`Path("/shared/code-folder").resolve().stem`

Which is similar to this.

```
dynamic_path = Path("/shared/code-folder").resolve()
name = dynamic_path.stem
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert path into string and split it.

If you want to get subfolder rev-383837338838373 try this:

```
str(Path("/shared/code-folder").resolve()).split('/)[1]
```